# How to stop IE This program might harm your computer warning

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a shrink wrapped product that I sell into a niche market. It seems we don't have enough downloads per year to establish a reputation with IE's Smart Screen filter, but the warnings are costing us sales. What do I have to do to convince SmartScreen filter our software is not malware?

Comment: What exactly is happening when? Are you distributing binary downloads?

Comment: That's correct Pekka ... an exe. My clients have been downloading my software for 16 years. My local market trusts me, but it seems IE's SmartScreen filter does not. Now that I'm moving my product into other markets this has become a major issue.

Answer (score 0):

We resolved this by having our app Certified for Windows 8. This might not suit everyone, but the warning went away.